# Why Do i Get A Data Mismatch Error in my VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I recently added a code to highlight in red the text box that the user did not fill out. I also added a code that would alert them with a message box. I have this dcount code but when i press the run button to execute the query i get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" whenever the user leaves the textbox blank. Can you help me with my code? Im getting an error on line:

If DCount("*", "Final - Union Query 07 & 08") > 0 Then

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
 If DCount("*", "Final - Union Query 07 & 08") > 0 Then
    Me!results.Requery
 ElseIf IsNull(Me.master_bill_a.Value) Or (Me.master_bill_a.Value = "") 
 Then
     MsgBox ("All criteria must be filled in the form")
    Me.master_bill_a.BorderColor = vbRed
    DoCmd.GoToControl "master_bill_a"
  ElseIf IsNull(Me.cash_date_a.Value) Or (Me.cash_date_a.Value = "") Then
    MsgBox ("All criteria must be filled in the form")
    Me.cash_date_a.BorderColor = vbRed
    DoCmd.GoToControl "cash_date_a"
  ElseIf IsNull(Me.billing_date_s) Then
    MsgBox ("All criteria must be filled in the form")
    Me.billing_date_s.BorderColor = vbRed
    DoCmd.GoToControl "billing_date_s"
 Else
    MsgBox ("There are no results to display. This may be an overpayment or 
 the wrong information was entered in the form.")

 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: which line please?

Comment: If DCount("*", "Final - Union Query 07 & 08") > 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets for that weird table name:

```
If DCount("*", "[Final - Union Query 07 & 08]") > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav but it did not resolve my issue. That is a Query by the way not a table. I usually get this error when i type something into the form but then remove it and click my "run" button to execute a query.

Comment: Then your query is what is failing.